# Construction of the equation from a given graph

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

The above diagram shows a sine-like graph is plotted in the range $0° \le x \le 360°$. It passes through 5 distinct points, namely A(0°, 0), B(90°, 2), C(180°, 0), D(270°, -2) and E(360°, 0). In which, B is the local maximum and D is the local minimum. The graph has the equation in the form y = P sin [Qx]; where Q is positive. Want to find all the possible values of P and Q.

(1) Using point B, I got 2 = P sin [Q(90°)]. This means P is not 0 (the initial result.)

(2) Using point C, I got 0 = P sin [Q(180°)]. This mean, together with the above result, Q = an integer.

(3) Applying the finding from (2) to (1), I found Q cannot be even.

(4) Let n be a natural number. By considering (1) again, I found:-

(a) when Q = 4n – 1, (i.e. Q = 3, 7, 11, … ), P = –2

(b) when Q = 4n – 3, (i.e. Q = 1, 5, 9, … ), P = 2.

My questions are:-

(1) Did I exhaust all the possibles?

(2) Should some of them be excluded?

(3) Is there any other (more elegant) way to obtain the answer?

Comment: Do you mind if there are more than one minimum and more than one maximum?

Comment: @tomi  Any other suggestion is welcomed. But beware that the graph shows that it has only one local maximum and one local minimum.

Comment: Yes, but by having Q = 3, 7, 11 etc and Q = 5, 9 etc you are allowing many more max and min. That's what leaves me confused.

Comment: @tomi I am sorry for supplying an invalid comment to you. The post was up there for quite awhile that I almost forgot. You are right that there are multiple maximums and minimums in the function but it must pass through the given 5 points.